# how to increase count on buttons by a single tap instead

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

When i click on the view it increases all button counts in that view and if I click on a button it dosent increase that button count or any of the other buttons . How do I change this so if i click on the button it increase it count and when i click anywhere in the view it dosent increase all the other button counts.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];

    [btnRed addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [btnYellow addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [btnGreen addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [btnBlue addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

    if (touch.view.tag == btnRed.tag)
    {
        redTouch++;
        NSLog(@"%i",redTouch);

    }
    if (touch.view.tag == btnYellow.tag)
    {
        yellowTouch++;
        NSLog(@"%i",yellowTouch);

    }
    if (touch.view.tag == btnGreen.tag)
    {
        greenTouch++;
        NSLog(@"%i",greenTouch);
    }
    if (touch.view.tag==btnBlue.tag)
    {
        blueTouch++;
        NSLog(@"%i",blueTouch);
    }
}
```

Comment: create new gesture recognizer on `touchesBegan`? I don't think that's a good idea. you should move it to `initWithFrame:`

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the view touch recogonized you dont need a touch recogonizer.
For the button, Setup an `IBAction` with `UIControlStateTouchUpInside` .When the button clicked the event gets executed and there increase the count there